# How do I track the progress of XCopy command while It's running?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, xcopy

> OPSYS: Win10Pro 64 bit
>
> RAM: 10GB

I created a batch file which I then saved to the desktop of the local Administrator account.

The batch file command line is this:

```
xcopy "F:\movies" "L:\movies" /d
```

I then created a Task Schedule in Task Scheduler to run the batch file.

I am now running it and do not see it running, other than when I refresh tasks in Task Scheduler Library view. There I see it and it says `'Running'`.

I am concerned that I do not see any kind of progress bar and I would like to see that. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: I apologize for lacking information. I also noticed that the file that is not copying over is a Read-only. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using software someone else made (like `XCOPY`) then the only easy route is to just end up being limited to whatever functionality was placed in there by the people who made that software.  Workarounds may exist (like jorgediaz-lr's answer... another possibility may be to look at free space on the destination drive, if you know how much is going to be copied), but your easiest workaround may be to try using other software.  Remember, `XCOPY` was made in the days when having the `/S` switch to include subdirectories was considered to be an advanced feature, because `COPY` didn't have that ability.

In the spirit of considering the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I point out that in Windows 10, you can check out the built-in `Robocopy`.  (If you can't see the program running, `Robocopy` also supports outputting to a log, which might be suitably helpful.)

I notice your `/d` option to `XCOPY`, which looks like is designed to just copy new files.

Although `Robocopy` has some options starting with `/I` to include some types of files, there isn't an option starting with `/I`, for including just new files... instead, the option that accomplishes this basic tasks will be the one that specifies to exclude old files.  (`/XO`)

`robocopy "F:\movies" "L:\movies" /XO`

Avoid `/NP` (show mp progress display), maybe use `/ETA` (show estimated time of arrival).

Comment: Interesting comment. I thought that xcopy was a part of Windows tools. the switch /l is L not an i, although I now have L in lower case, d and i as switches for that. /l should show the files to be copied while /i assumes the destination is a folder. I am still not able to copy using the batch file at this point. Really frustrating because it copied other files just fine.

Comment: If you add a `/E` then you will copy subdirectories (including empty ones).  Go to a command prompt and run `Robocopy /? >> robohelp.txt` (and then open up that robohelp.txt text file).  I'm thinking that `/ETA` probably modifies the progress, but it sounds like you're in just as good of a position to test that as I am.

Answer (score 4):

You can view that in task manager.
If total file size to be downloaded is 4 GB then go to

1. the program

   > Task Manager -> Details tab -> Right click -> Select columns -> I/o write bytes column
2. Select "xcopy.exe" process.

The number of bytes written will indicate how much is done & what remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

That application allows seeing which files are open by any process, so you can check the opened files by xcopy

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to view the progress of the copy as it occurs.I have just ran into another problem that I didn't notice before:
The backup is not backing up now after changing batch file to read:
"xcopy "F:\*.*" "L:\" /d /l /i"

Answer (score 0):

You can view Read B/sec and Write B/sec in task manager

**BUT** looking for the Read B/sec and Write B/sec for the XCopy process is **NOT the correct answer.**

The processes (one to read, one to write) that actually perform the copying on XCopy's behalf is **system**.

If you use **Disk Activity** in **Resource Monitor** and look for the filename of the destination file being written, or source file being read from to you can see the actual copy process and an indication of current B/sec of copy process, unfortunately it doesn't give you an indication of progress other than data is being read from and written at the indicated speeds.